# Connecting gvSIG with SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, gvsig

I am working for the first time with gvSIG and SQL SERVER, I want to connect gvsig with spatial database SQL SERVER.

I don't know how to, Is it by using a protocol and which one ? plz help me

Comment: I think its not possible..check following link http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/SQL-Server-2008-driver-for-gvSIG-td4106227.html still researching on this issue

Comment: May be using ODBC driver you can try..

Comment: yes but ODBC do not support geometries data, only alphanumeric data

Answer (score 2):

gvSIG doesn't have a driver for SQL Server at this moment, at least there isn't at project level.

Yes you can connect through ODBC for alphanumerical data, but there is no driver for the geometry or geography data types.

Comment: so there isn't another way for the geometry or geography data.
because my data is SQL SERVER and am working with resources of gvSIG on eclipse and i need this connection, is it simple to create the driver by simply migrating the request of Postgis for example to SQL SERVER Request ?

Comment: Ugh, that depends a lot on your Java knowledge. I wouldn't say it's easy because, well, even being a major database vendor no one has done the job.

I recomend you to ask at the gvSIG mailing list to reach more developers that will help you http://listserv.gva.es/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/gvsig_internacional